# How to put WebView inside View

Tags: react-native, reactjs

I need to customize my `WebView` in React Native with header and footer. but `WebView` does not load URL when put inside `View`. How can I achieve this functionality?

```
 <View style={styles.mainSection}>
   <WebView
     source={{uri: this.props.mediaItem.source}}
     style={{marginTop: 20}}
   />
 </View>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem is related to the size of the `WebView` component. Try to put `flex: 1` into your `WebView` style.